# What happens when multiple Async calls occur before the delegates finish?

Tags: .net, asynchronous, concurrency, asyncsocket

I'm trying to write a fairly simple application that passes data between two sockets.  However, I'm a little confused on using the NetworkStream Async operations (BeginRead and EndRead).

For example:

```
while (myNetworkStream.DataAvailable)
  myNetworkStream.BeginRead(mBrowserDataBuffer, 0, mBrowserDataBuffer.Length, new AsyncCallback(ProcessNetworkStreamRead), myNetworkStream);
```

When I call BeginRead, the method will immediately return and start a thread to perform the read operation.  However, in my loop above, what happens if BeginRead gets called AGAIN before the delegate finishes?

Basically I want my delegate to append incoming data to a larger buffer and then processes messages as they are complete.  I need to use async operations because while one socket is reading I'd like to also read and process from the other socket as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Only one thread** must read from the same stream.

One trick is to call `BeginRead` again in your `EndRead` callback. Doing it in the  loop as you have shown is not correct.